# Where in Elite Dangerous are the Bookmarks stored?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

Where in Elite Dangerous are the Bookmarks stored? I am looking to copy all my bookmarks from one account to another.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarks in Elite Dangerous are stored on the server and to my knowledge there is no way to copy them from one account to another.